# Multiple warnings when launching QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I just installed QGIS 2.18.4 Las Palmas on Ubuntu 16.04 with the UbuntuGIS dependencies. While it seems to be working (for the moment), I get a barrage of warnings when I launch it from the terminal.

I added the key:

```
wget -O - http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2016.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 073D307A618E5811
gpg --export --armor 073D307A618E5811 | sudo apt-key add -
```

I added the following to my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb     http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb     http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
```

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

The following warnings appear after launching QGIS from my terminal:

```
myuser@myuser:~$ qgis
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
Warning: QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /home/jmnoor/.qgis2//project_templates
Warning: QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QgsPanelWidgetStack "mWidgetStack", which already has a layout
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Toolbox" under id 258
```

Anyone experience this?

Comment: Your installation commands seem to be correct. Apparently, I get only two of your warnings. You can safely ignore them, unless something else is missing.

Comment: I get similar warnings - there are no english translation files so the first two can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thank you guys for taking the time to help. My install seems to be working fine thus far. I will keep an eye on it. This Las Palmas is pretty slick.

Comment: I also experience similar warnings with the same setup of Ubuntu and QGIS -- so thanks for the help with the question and for the answers from others.